# Simple way to isolate video signal

Tags: isolation, video, ground-loop

To avoid ground loops I want to isolate several video channels (base-band).
I have a video source with 4 channel, they all share the same ground.

I'm thinking about some transformer like used in audio application with an impedance of 75 ohm. Two issues: I can't find a suitable product, I will lost the DC offset.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For composite video you'd need a wideband transformer, as the signal has quite a bit of low frequency information.

Well, I simply googled "composite video transformer" and came up with [this](https://www.amazon.fr/Cables-To-Go-41145-COMPOSITE/dp/B000SNS6MI).

EDIT:

Composite video bandwidth seems limited to less than 10MHz so I can reuse the research I did to select a SPDIF transformer. So, Murata DA102.

[image]

Note transformers don't care about the 75R impedance. They do introcude a discontinuity though, so the length of transmission like from the transformer to the receiver should be kept short.

Comment: Thanks, I can find other similar products available. But I'd like to put it on my PCB board. I'm looking for the inside transformers. Perhaps I'm searching them with a wrong keyword!

Comment: Maybe ATB3225-75011CT (http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/400/f_balun_atb3225_en-959342.pdf) could work? I'm going to connect pin 2 and 5 to use it as 1:1 transformer rather than a balun...

Comment: Nope, it's for higher frequencies than composite, check my edit

Comment: I got it. Murata DA102 is no more available, but now I know the characteristics I should looking for!

Comment: And for restoring the DC, which may be important in a video circuit unless the downstream device can do it, look at a simple diode "[clamper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamper_(electronics))".

Comment: DA102JC is in stock at mouser ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, composhite has a large low frequency component extending down at least as for as the field sync at 50 or ~60Hz, and really to DC. This makes classical transformers difficult, at least unless followed by a fairly clever DC restore circuit.

The standard solution in the broadcast game back in the day was a 'longitudinal stop coil' aka "Video humbucker" which was a common mode choke wound with small diameter coax on a standard iron transformer core, they were very effective, and are I believe still available.